# How do I build a corner bench for my deck?

Tags: wood, furniture, decking, bench

I am totally new to DIY and wanted to take my first steps with a simple project - a corner bench.

I have decking outside already, and want to use the same decking wood for my bench. Something similar to this

[image: bench example 1]

[image: bench example 2]

I thought this would be a standard sort of newbie project and was expecting to find loads of plans, drawings, tutorials etc how to make one. Unfortunately an hour spent googling did not show anything useful.

Does anyone have some good resources that can help me learn the basics to allow me to complete this project? I'm not necessarily looking for a complete set of drawings/instruction for a corner bench (although that would help) but some basic instruction on building basic furniture.

For example, how do I attach the legs without the screws showing? How do I complete the corner join of the benches etc.

Any hints or tips for this newbie will be hugely helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple really assuming you have the proper tools.

- Cut your 4x4's to 18 inch length
- Build a frame
- Attach to the 4x4 posts
- Cut wood to fit the surface of the frame
- Add lateral support to the 4x4 posts

To join 2 benches at a corner, figure out your corner angle and modify the plans to match.

[Wooden Bench Plans Website](http://www.diydeckplans.com/tutorials/benches/wood-deck-bench-plan)
[image: Wooden Bench Plans]